# Why can I set dimensions of a absolutely positioned element using percentages even tho it's parent element doesn't have any set dimensions?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div inside the html's body,why is it when I set it's position to absolute I can set it's width/height using percentages?The parent element doesn't have any set width/height so where does the child element get it's reference size from?I have added my code bellow.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wut.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you set `position:absolute;` on an element it becomes relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, if none exists it is then relative to the initial containing block that is `viewport/<html>`, and the `viewport/<html>` have dimesnions

Comment: from the duplicate read : *Absolute Positioning Exception*